# How to make a sprite move back and forth on a platform in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

After about of hour of disaster and modification on my code, I can't seem to get my enemy sprite to move back and forth on a platform. So any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Test File, Crafted Super Fast....

```
import pygame, sys, os

GAME_TITLE = "GAME"
WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 1280, 720
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
FPS = 60

ENEMY_ACC = 0.3
ENEMY_FRICTION = -0.12
ENEMY_GRAVITY = 0.5

vec = pygame.math.Vector2

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, w, h):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.group = self.game.platform_list
        self.image = pygame.Surface((1280, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, RED, (x, y, w, h))


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.group = self.game.enemy_list
        self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, BLUE, (200, 200, 100, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = vec(pos)
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
        self.direction = "R"
        self.engage = False

    def update(self):
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platform_list, False)
        if hits:
            plat_right = hits[0].rect.right
            plat_left = hits[0].rect.left
            self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
            self.vel.y = 0

        if self.direction == "R" and not self.engage:
            if self.rect.right >= plat_right:
                self.direction = "L"
                self.acc.x = -ENEMY_ACC
        if self.direction == "L" and not self.engage:
            if self.rect.left <= plat_left:
                self.direction = "R"
                self.acc.x = -ENEMY_ACC

        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * ENEMY_FRICTION
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos
        self.acc = vec(0, ENEMY_GRAVITY)

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.font.init()
        os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
        pygame.display.set_caption(GAME_TITLE)
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def run(self):
        enemy = Enemy(self, (200, 500))
        self.enemy_list.add(enemy)

        platform = Platform(self, 0, 620, 1280, 100)
        self.platform_list.add(platform)

        while True:
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        self.enemy_list.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.window.fill(BLACK)
        self.platform_list.draw(self.window)
        self.enemy_list.draw(self.window)
        pygame.display.flip()

def main():
    g = Game()
    g.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're making it very difficult for us to help you if you don't give us an executable [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which we can test and debug.

Comment: I can provide more code if necessary, I believe I've provided the necessary code to identify the problem.

Comment: But if its necessary I'll start crafting up a test file.

Comment: There added a some code, hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Much better. There's still an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'plat_right' referenced before assignment` in line 50.

Comment: Ya I know that, but that's not the error I'm talking about, that error's mainly due to the fact I've been rearranging my code for hours. The error I can't seem fix is to the enemy sprite movement stated above.

Comment: But what is the program supposed to do there if `plat_right` and `plat_left` are not defined?

Comment: That's one problem I can't find a probable solution for and there's most likely more problems in that enemy class, hence why I've been rearranging my code for hours, and also why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148854/discussion-between-skrx-and-18-triston-lehmann).

Comment: @18TristonLehmann When you ask questions on Stackoverflow, please accept the answer if it helped you or leave a comment explaining why the answer wasn't sufficient. You've asked 8 questions where all have an answer and 3 of them where you've seemingly confirmed it help you. By marking the question as accepted you notify future readers and the answerer that the answer solved your question. It'll also give you rep points so you can use more features of Stackoverflow (like the chat) and it rewards the person posting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example without the `acc` attribute. Just accelerate the `self.vel` by adding the `ENEMY_GRAVITY`, update the `self.pos` and `self.rect`, then if it collides with the platform see if the right or left edge is reached and then just invert the velocity.

I've set the `ENEMY_GRAVITY` to `3` and call `clock.tick(30)` to limit the frame rate. The `direction` attribute doesn't seem to be necessary anymore.

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.group = self.game.enemy_list
        self.image = pygame.Surface((60, 60))
        self.image.fill((30, 90, 200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=pos)
        self.pos = vec(pos)
        self.vel = vec(3, 0)
        self.engage = False

    def update(self):
        self.vel.y += ENEMY_GRAVITY
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platform_list, False)
        for plat in hits:
            self.pos.y = plat.rect.top
            self.rect.bottom = plat.rect.top
            self.vel.y = 0

            if self.vel.x > 0 and not self.engage:
                if self.rect.right >= plat.rect.right:
                    self.vel = vec(-3, 0)  # Reverse the horizontal velocity.
            elif self.vel.x < 0 and not self.engage:
                if self.rect.left <= plat.rect.left:
                    self.vel = vec(3, 0)  # Reverse the horizontal velocity.
```